# Is the location of Kailash described in Purans ? What is the path or way to go to Kailash?

Tags: kailasa

Shiva lives in Kailash which is located on earth. Is there way or path mentioned in Purans to reach the Kailash ?
Is the location of Kailash described in Puranas ?

Comment: There are different understandings of the term Kailash. This link might help http://namahshivaya.net/where-does-shiva-reside-does-he-live-on-kailash/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Location of Mount Kailasha as Described in **Mahabharata Drona Parva Section LXXXI.:**

> ***Hearing these words of Krishna, Dhananjaya, having touched water, sat on the earth with concentrated mind and thought of the god Bhava. After he had thus sat with rapt mind at that hour called Brahma of auspicious indications, Arjuna saw himself journeying through the sky with Kesava. And Partha, possessed of the speed of the mind, seemed to reach, with Kesava, the sacred foot of Himavat and the Manimat mountain abounding in many brilliant gems and frequented by Siddhas and Caranas. And the lord Kesava seemed to have caught hold of his left arm. And he seemed to see many wonderful sights as he reached (those place). And Arjuna of righteous soul then seemed to arrive at the White mountain on the north.***
>
> ***And then he beheld, in the pleasure-gardens of Kuvera the beautiful lake decked with lotuses. And he also saw that foremost of rivers, viz., the Ganga full of water. And then he arrived at the regions about the Mandara mountains. Those regions were covered with trees that always bore blossoms and fruits. And they abounded with stones lying scattered about, that were all transparent crystal. And they were inhabited by lions and tigers and abounded with animals of diverse kinds.***
>
> ***And they were adorned with many beautiful retreats of ascetics, echoing with the sweet notes of delightful warblers. And they resounded also with the songs of Kinnaras. Graced with many golden and silver peaks, they were illumined with diverse herbs and plants. And many Mandara trees with their pretty loads of flowers, adorned them. And then Arjuna reached the mountains called Kala that looked like a mound of antimony. And then he reached the summit called Brahmatunga, and then many rivers, and then many inhabited provinces. And he arrived at Satasinga, and the woods known by the name of Sharyati. And then he beheld the sacred spot known as the Horse-head, and then the region of Atharvana. And then he beheld that prince of mountains called Vrishadansa, and the great Mandara, abounding in Apsaras, and graced with the presence of the Kinnaras.***
>
> ***And roaming on that mountain, Partha, with Krishna, beheld a spot of earth adorned with excellent fountains, decked with golden mineral, and possessed of the splendour of the lunar rays, and having many cities and towns. And he also beheld many seas of wonderful forms and diverse mines of wealth. And thus going through the sky and firmament and the earth, he reached the spot called Vishnupada. And wandering, with Krishna in his company, he came down with great velocity, like a shaft shot (from a bow).***
>
> ***And soon Partha beheld a blazing mountain whose splendour equalled that of the planets, the constellations, or fire. And arrived at that mountain, he beheld on its top, the high-souled god having the bull for his mark, and ever engaged in ascetic penances, like a thousand suns collected together, and blazing with his own effulgence. Trident in hand, matted locks on the head, of snow-white colour, he was robed in bark and skin. Endued with great energy, his body seemed to be flaming with a thousand eyes. And he was seated with Parvati and many creatures of brilliant forms (around him).***

I hope this clarifies all your queries. Prd..